# multiple sites on docker container

Tags: docker, apache, virtualhost

I am completely new to docker, php and apache, I am trying to run my sample website on apache server in a docker container. It works fine. And my dockerfile is following:

```
From php:7.2-apache
Copy Site/ /var/www/html/
Run echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
Expose 80
```

How can I have another website on the same apache sever in the docker container, for example "website1", in xampp I could change the httpd.conf file and add virtual host.  but what should I do in docker container?

**Update**

**============================================**

I update the files as the following, This is docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3.9'
services:
    apache:
        build: .
        container_name: php_cont
        volumes:
            - './apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
            - './Site1/site1.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf'
            - './Site2/site2.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.conf'
        ports:
            - '80:80'
```

This is the site.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "d:\Temp\Site1"
 ServerName site1Name
 <Directory "d:\Temp\Site1">
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

This is the site2.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "d:\Temp\Site2"
 ServerName site2Name
 <Directory "d:\Temp\Site2">
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

and I addded these two line to hosts file in windows=>system32=>driver=>etc

```
  127.0.0.1 site1Name
  127.0.0.1 site2Name
```

but when I surf to site1Name or site2Name on the browser, there is no success!

Answer (score 2):

The idea of Docker is that every application (website in you case) has its own environment. You can then upgrade the PHP version for one application without affecting the others. So you should have a Dockerfile per website.

To answer your question “how to direct visitors to the correct container?”: please take a look into Reverse Proxies. There are plenty of Docker images available like Nginx and Traefik. These can also take care of SSL certificates for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), but you also can use **Volume** in both `docker run` command and `docker-compose`.

**docker-compose**

First of all let's see `docker-compose`. Create a file called `docker-compose.yml` with the following contents:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    apache:
        build: .
        hostname: OPTIONAL
        container_name: OPTIONAL
        volumes:
            - './apache/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
            - './apache/site1.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf'
        ports:
            - '80:80'
```

The two keywords `hostname` and `container_name` are optional and you can change their values or even remove these two lines.

Regarding `volumes`, copy your `apache2.conf` to a path like `./apache` and do your edits in this file.

Then add another file called `site1.conf`. Here is my conf file as an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName some_name.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@name
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

For each site you can create another file and add it to `volumes`.

Now after everything is done, run this command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**docker run command**

If you want to use `docker run` command, you can do like this (the above paths in `./apache` in the below are the same):

```
docker run IMAGE_NAME -v './apache/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf' -v './apache/site1.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf' -dp80:80
```

**Update 1**

Edit your `Dockerfile`:

```
From php:7.2-apache
Copy Site/ /var/www/html/
Run echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY site1.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY site2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY apache2.sh /root/
RUN bash /root/apache2.sh
RUN rm /root/apache2.sh
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
Expose 80
```

`apache2.sh`:

```
service apache2 start
a2ensite site1
a2ensite site2
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am working on Windows 10,so I don't have /home/apache/apache2.conf, or /home/apache/site1.conf, what should I do for that?

Comment: Do you use Docker Desktop? Or you're using Docker in a VM?

Comment: I am using Docker Desktop

Comment: No success  , is the dockerfile ok?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You also can remove `Copy Site/ /var/www/html/` in `Dockerfile` because you are binding volume

Comment: it doesnt work, by using the above yml, I even can not surf none of two sites

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` to see if they're running

Comment: Yes it is, I can see it docker desktop container list, but it is not possible to surf it on the browser

Comment: Which way do you use? `docker run` command or `docker-compose` file? For `docker-compose` I added `ports` mapping.

Comment: I updated the post according to your suggestion , but there is success. Thank you. and I use the docker-compose

Comment: You're welcome. I also edited my answer since in Windows paths should be `relative`, not `absolute`. I see your edited question and happy your problem is solved:)

Comment: there is an misunderstanding. My problem has not solved yet, and I cann't access , the multiple seites that I have mentioned their name in Site.conf